# Why Is There a Parasitic Sine Wave at My Signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, filter, signal, active-filter

I am trying to build an EEG device (following the openEEG open source design). I amplify the small EEG signal with an AD620AN intrumental amplifier, then pass it through a high pass filter to eliminate any DC component. Later on the signal is amplified again (using a TLC272 Op-Amp), passed through another high pass filter with the same specifications and finally gets filtered with a low pass filter with cut-off frequency of 59Hz. Last pole of the filter is a low pass pole with a 7.5K resistor and a 220u capacitor which is present at the second sheet of the schematics. I power the circuit with a 5V supply and use a buffered 2V as virtual ground. I use my analog oscilloscopes calibration signal for test purposes.

The problem is that the square signal becomes this distorted signal after it passes the first high pass filter. After the second amplification, it becomes this weird low frequency sine wave with a high frequency sine wave component added to it. Finally, after the last low pass filter, the square wave is now a complete “sine” wave with little distortions. Circuit schematic and all the mentioned distorted signals are given below as visuals.

**Datasheet of TLC272:**

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc272.pdf?ts=1677164241206&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

**Datasheet of AD620AN:**

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad620.pdf

**Schematic 1**

[image: Schematic]

**Last Pole of the Filter:**

[image: the rc network is the last pole]

**Calibration Square Wave Signal:**

[image: Calibration square signal]

**Amplified Signal by AD620AN:**

[image: Signal after the AD620AN]

**Signal with two sine components? Just before the last pole of the low-pass filter at the end:**

[image: Signal with two sine components?]

**Final Output:**

[image: Final output]

I have tried simulating the signal at LTSpice to see if the behaviour of the circuit is correct, and it works as the same except the low frequency sine wave component at the second stage of the amplification.

Comment: How is the circuitry constructed?  PCB, perfboard, protoboard?

Comment: Is the low frequency sine wave the same frequency as you line voltage (50 or 60 Hz)?

Comment: @Mattman944 unfortunately I cant say for sure since my scope cant take the signal to frequency domain. If it was, wouldnt it be at the previous steps too?

Comment: @rdtsc it is on a PCB, I etched it myself.

Comment: what level and frequency is your scope's cal signal? What level and frequency does your circuit expect? If I read your scope display correctly (guessing the symbol '>' means 'per division'), the calibrator is at 4 kHz, and the large LF signal is at 200 Hz. However, my scope calibrator, and most others I've used is at 1 kHz, which would put the large signal at 50 Hz, or mains hum.

Comment: Have you tried using your PC’s sound card as a signal generator, oscilloscope and spectrum analyser? There’s open source tools available to do this. Might be a bit easier than your analog scope.

Comment: wouldn't it be on previous steps too? It does appear to be on previous steps, just at different levels. The saw-toothy wave appears to be multiple traces, which means there's another frequency present. That effect is also just visible on the square wave. As you go through filters, you would expect the ratio of high frequency and low frequency signals to change, as they do in your next two images.

Comment: The frequency of the compensation test signal is 1kHz.  This signal is single ended so doesn’t represent a typical input signal.

Comment: The Sallen-Key filter has a very high gain. Although the high component ratio should stabilize. Still at gains > 5 component tolerance becomes tighter.

Comment: Good chance you're seeing 60Hz "in the air"  (or 50Hz if you're in Europe).  Slow down the scopes sweep rate to about 20ms/division.   That'll make it very easy to see if indeed you're capturing 60Hz

Comment: @KyleB you are right! I am at Europe and the big signal shape has around 50Hz frequency. But now Im confused about the last signal. The final output with little noise, which is also around 50Hz. Does this means that the mains signal so dominant that my actual signal is just a noise? The calibration signal is a p-p 200mV and 1kHz signal.

Comment: @Kartman can you suggest me your choice?

Comment: @Neil_UK but the calibration signal has 200mV p-p, wouldnt the square wave also be wavy like third signal if there was mains hum in it?

Comment: @Tombeki it **IS** wavy, look at your first scope shot. Unfortunately, because of your fast timebase, only a very tiny part of the 50 Hz wave is visible, but you can see it in the divergence of the two traces on the right hand side of the screen. The multiple traces are much more visible in the saw-toothy shot. Play with the triggering on your scope, both level and if there's any filtering available, to change these pictures slightly.

Comment: What kind of power supply are you using? You may need an isolation transformer. An "isolated" flyback converter is likely to have a significant "ghost" component.

Comment: @Tombeki, audacity would be a starting point. There’s plenty of other options,both free and paid. Google something like soundcard oscilloscope.